# Django get_absolute url error on the template

Tags: django, django-models

With django I have this following error for the .get_absolute_url method:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '(2016, '04', '17', 'ab quae natus laboriosam pariatur inventore odio quisquam aliquam est quas aliquid')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<year>\\d{4})/(?P<month>\\d{2})/(?P<day>\\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

ipython shell

```
     41     author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
     42     body = models.TextField()
---> 43     publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
     44     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     45     updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

my model look like this

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
            ('draft', 'Draft'),
            ('published', 'Published'),
            )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date="publish")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="draft")

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish', )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, 
            self.publish.strftime('%m'),
            self.publish.strftime('%d'),
            self.slug])
```

I don't understand this part of the  error `and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` because previously it said that it found this argument `...with arguments '(2016, '04', '17', ...`

Answer (score 0):

I had to `slugify` all the slugs in my db

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

bpost = Post.objects.all()
for p in bpost():
    p.title = slugify(title)
    p.save()
```